# How to search for files in multiple sub folders?

Tags: excel, vba

With the help of some previous questions here, I was able to write a code that searches for files with a specific name in multiple subfolders.

I have a folder with multiple subfolders and some subfolders further contain more subfolders. The codes that I found searches all these subfolders and also sub-subfolders. But I want my code to only search through the subfolders I.e. only the first layer.

Could anyone help me with this?

```
Function Recurse(sPath As String) As String

Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim myFolder As Folder
Dim mySubFolder As Folder
Dim mySubSubFolder As Folder
Dim myFile As File
Dim Path As String
Dim f As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sPath)
Dim myComp

For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.SubFolders

    f = -1

    For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files

        If ((InStr(myFile.Name, "Beurteilungsblatt") > 0) And (InStr(myFile.Name, ".xlsm") > 0)) Then
            Debug.Print (myFile.Name)
            f = f + 1
        End If
    Next

    Dim arr()
    ReDim arr(f)

    i = 0
        For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files
            If ((InStr(myFile.Name, "Beurteilungsblatt") > 0) And (InStr(myFile.Name, ".xlsm") > 0)) Then
                Workbooks.Open (myFile.Path)
                Set wbok1Current = ActiveWorkbook
                arr(i) = wbok1Current.Worksheets("Beurteilungsblatt").Range("FK10")
                i = i + 1
                wbok1Current.Close
            End If
        Next

    For j = 0 To f - 1
        Dim str As String
        Dim str1 As String
        str = arr(j)
        str1 = arr(j + 1)
        myComp = StrComp(str, str1, 1)
        If (myComp = 0) Then
            GoTo Continuej
        Else
            MsgBox ("Die Beurteilungsblätter sind nicht von selben Fahrzeug!" & vbCrLf & "Please Check " & str & " and " & str1 & ".")
            GoTo NextFolder
        End If
Continuej:
    Next j

    For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files

        If ((InStr(myFile.Name, "Beurteilungsblatt") > 0) And (InStr(myFile.Name, ".xlsm") > 0)) Then

          '  MsgBox myFile.Name & " in " & myFile.path 'Or do whatever you want with the file
          '  Exit For


                Workbooks.Open (myFile.Path)
                Set wbok1Current = ActiveWorkbook


                If (IsRangeEmpty(Range("CR10:EY10")) And wbok1Current.Worksheets("Beurteilungsblatt").Range("EZ10").Value = "0" And wbok1Current.Worksheets("Beurteilungsblatt").Range("FA10").Value = "0" And wbok1Current.Worksheets("Beurteilungsblatt").Range("FB10").Value = "0" And wbok1Current.Worksheets("Beurteilungsblatt").Range("FJ10").Value = "") Then
                    GoTo ContinueDo
                End If

                Path = wbok1Current.Path

    ' do something


ContinueDo:
                    wbok1Current.Close
                    wbokCurrent.Activate

        End If

    Next
    Recurse = Recurse(mySubFolder.Path)

    wbokCurrent.Activate
    Dim dateinam As String
    dateinam = Worksheets("Fahrzeug").Range("CC2").Value
    If dateinam = "" Then
        Exit Function
    Else
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'    wbokCurrent.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Auswertung_" & dateinam & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    wbokCurrent.SaveCopyAs FileName:=Path & "\" & dateinam & ".xlsm" 'FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    Range("A13:CD53").Select                'Löschen
    Application.CutCopyMode = False         'Löschen
    Selection.ClearContents                 'Löschen
    Range("A13").Select                     'Löschen

NextFolder:

Next
```

End Function

Comment: If you could perhaps share the code you are using? It's difficult to help when you haven't posted it

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: What I don't understand is that when I write,

For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.Subfolders
   For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files
......
why is it looking into subfolders of subfolder? I have told it to look for only Files not Folders...

Comment: The `Recurse = Recurse(mySubFolder.Path)` recursively calls the function to process all subfolders. Try removing it.